# Eigensystem analysis in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, eigenvector

The example for DEigensystem on the mathematica site is:

```
DEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x], {x}],DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 4]
```

This works perfectly.  I want to modify this to find eigenvectors/values for a fourth order system: y''''=lambda*y with BC on y,y', so I use:

```
 DEigensystem[{y''''[x], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y[1] == 0, y'[1] == 0},y[x], {x, 0, 1}, 4]
```

With the unhelpful return:

```
DEigensystem[{y^4[x], y[0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, y[1] == 0, Derivative[1][y][1] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 1}, 4]
```

This eigenproblem has a neat exact solution, so I wanted to see if Mathematica would find it. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "get no useful return"? Is it not giving you the correct exact solution, or are you getting an error as the output?

Comment: @jmoon  Sorry, I included the return in my edit of the OP

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not passing in the equations in the correct format. If you read the "Details and Options" section in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DEigensystem.html), you see:

"DEigensystem[eqns,u,t,{x,y,…}∈Ω,n]
gives the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for solutions u of the time-dependent differential equations eqns."

and

"The equations eqns are specified as in DSolve."

Then, once you reference the [DSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) documentation, you see that you need to specify the equations like this:
"DSolve[eqn,u,x] solves a differential equation for the function u, with independent variable x."

I'm assuming you want to solve the equation

y''''(x) = y(x)

with the initial conditions

y[0] = 0, y'[0] = 0, y[1] = 0, y'[1] = 0

so you might want to try

```
DEigensystem = [{y''''[x] == y[x], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y[1] == 0, y'[1] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 1}, 4]
```

Disclaimer: I don't have access to Mathematica, so all I can do is theorize on what the error is. Feel free to edit if you have a working solution.

Comment: When I copy and paste your suggestion, the response is 'Syntax: "DEigensystem=" cannot be followed by "[{y''''[x]==y[x],y[0]==0,y'[0]==0,y[1]==0,y'[1]==0},y[x],{x,0,1},4]".'  Thanks so much for what you have done so far.

Comment: Huh. That's a strange error. Thanks for letting me know, I'm looking into it more right now

Comment: Try this: DEigensystem = [{y''''[x] == y[x], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y[1] == 0, y'[1] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 4]

Comment: Same error as before, "cannot be followed by ....".  Also I found this link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133374/how-fragile-is-deigensystem  that suggests DEigensystem is very very particular about what it will and will not do.